# I want to stop applet caching

Tags: java, caching, applet

I want to disable applet caching so every time I put new version of jar file of my applet  the client should see the new app and not the cached one.
how can I do that ?
note :
I read this page 
http://cyclic.ucsd.edu/javafiles.html
but I still need to press f5 to get the new version 
is there pragmatically way to do what the page http://cyclic.ucsd.edu/javafiles.html has done

I use

```
<html>
<title>The Hello, World Applet</title>
<hr>
<applet code=javaapplication4.test.class 
        archive="JavaApplication4.jar?v=200406180000"
        width=600 height=400>
</applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

and when I update the JavaApplication4.jar no thing happens

Comment: One possible solution is to add a time stamp to the name, so it's got a new name every time. But then you need to update the URL as well.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: I forgot that with Java you cannot just change the file name, so this solution might not be viable here. But in general, a file is cached based on its name, so when the name changes it will be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the v=200406180000 to another number when I want to update my JavaApplication4.jar file